# UITableView redraw without data source call

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

With `UISearchDisplayController` is it possible to have `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method call without calling data source for actual number of rows?

Here is stack trace for crash (iOS 7.1.2):

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                       0x3085df83 __exceptionPreprocess + 131
1   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x3b0d8ccf objc_exception_throw + 36
2   CoreFoundation                       0x307947cb -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 228
3   MyApp                                0x0016cbb3 -[BaseContactsViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (BaseContactsViewController.m:338)
4   UIKit                                0x331ad8f7 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 408
5   UIKit                                0x33154c27 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1804
6   UIKit                                0x33147c5d -[UITableView _setNeedsVisibleCellsUpdate:withFrames:] + 166
7   UIKit                                0x33147ba3 -[UITableView _rectChangedWithNewSize:oldSize:] + 480
8   UIKit                                0x331541cd -[UITableView setBounds:] + 262
9   UIKit                                0x3317066d -[UIView(Geometry) _applyISEngineLayoutValues] + 278
10  UIKit                                0x33094549 -[UIView(Geometry) _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 162
11  UIKit                                0x33172ca3 -[UIScrollView _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 40
12  CoreFoundation                       0x307a2abd __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 90
13  CoreFoundation                       0x307a29cb -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 196
14  UIKit                                0x330851bd -[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 118
15  UIKit                                0x331712e9 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _is_layout] + 134
16  UIKit                                0x3307afc1 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutSubviews] + 70
17  UIKit                                0x3307ad59 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 378
18  QuartzCore                           0x32cf862b -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 140
19  QuartzCore                           0x32cf3e3b CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 348
20  UIKit                                0x3308fe8b -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 548
21  UIKit                                0x33129eeb -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 808
22  UIKit                                0x331ddcc5 -[UINavigationController _setNavigationBarHidden:edge:duration:] + 1270
23  UIKit                                0x3326c011 -[UINavigationController _setNavigationBarHidden:edgeIfNotNavigating:duration:] + 530
24  UIKit                                0x33196109 -[UISearchDisplayController setActive:animated:] + 8614
25  UIKit                                0x3326abcd -[UISearchDisplayController searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:] + 246
26  UIKit                                0x3326aaaf -[UISearchBar(UISearchBarStatic) _searchFieldBeginEditing] + 88
27  UIKit                                0x330b0037 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 88
28  UIKit                                0x330affd7 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 28
29  UIKit                                0x330affb1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 42
30  UIKit                                0x3309b717 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 372
31  UIKit                                0x3309acfd -[UITextField willAttachFieldEditor:] + 666
32  UIKit                                0x33097805 -[UIFieldEditor becomeFieldEditorForView:] + 818
33  UIKit                                0x33176f15 -[UITextField _becomeFirstResponder] + 158
34  UIKit                                0x3326a91f -[UISearchBarTextField _becomeFirstResponder] + 76
35  UIKit                                0x330f9127 -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 360
36  UIKit                                0x330f93e7 -[UIView(Hierarchy) becomeFirstResponder] + 104
37  UIKit                                0x33175c17 -[UITextField becomeFirstResponder] + 44
38  UIKit                                0x333fe579 -[UISearchBar(UISearchBarStatic) becomeFirstResponder] + 34
39  UIKit                                0x33200fed _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 194
40  UIKit                                0x330ac4e3 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 1136
41  UIKit                                0x33453aed ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke + 46
42  UIKit                                0x33073353 _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 216
43  UIKit                                0x33071a9b _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 280
44  UIKit                                0x330aad49 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 770
45  UIKit                                0x330aa66f -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 664
46  UIKit                                0x3307f8cd -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 194
47  UIKit                                0x3307df77 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7100
48  CoreFoundation                       0x3082920b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
49  CoreFoundation                       0x308286db __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204
50  CoreFoundation                       0x30826ecf __CFRunLoopRun + 620
51  CoreFoundation                       0x30791ebf CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
52  CoreFoundation                       0x30791ca3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
53  GraphicsServices                     0x356eb663 GSEventRunModal + 136
54  UIKit                                0x330de14d UIApplicationMain + 1134
55  MyApp                                0x0013f55b main (main.m:16)
56  libdyld.dylib                        0x3b5e5ab7 start + 0
```

As I understand it there was a tap in search bar edit field and search was started. If we have right number of rows from data source, it is not possible to have such exception. So my suggestion is data source was not asked for number of rows.

Here is my data source implementation:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (_searchDisplayController.active)
    {
        // return number of search items
    }

    // return number of regular items in section
}
```

I use `active` property to know if I need to provide number of search items instead of regular items. My another suggestion is that for some reason search controller was not active at time of data source call but was active in time of table delegate call.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, you can just return a empty cell without representing the data source.

```
tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    return cell;
}
```

Your crash is caused by `BaseContactsViewController.m:338`. You are trying to get object at index 0 from an empty data set. What do you have on that line?

Comment: AFAIK if numberOfSectionsInTableView: returned zero, cellForRowAtIndexPath: will not called. So it is not possible to have empty array indexing exception.

Comment: Your suggestion in the post is correct. UISearchDisplayController does not call numberOfSectionsInTableView: If you set a breakpoint in it, it won't break. I experienced it in one of my projects. I will want to avoid UISearchDisplayController for this confusion. Also it is deprecated https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/

Comment: I think I understand your question now. To the question, I think it is not possible to have tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath called without calling data source for actual number of rows.